# KeyedTuple with a list of related data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2

I have a couple of simple models that look something like this:

```
class StoreImage(Base):
    imagepath = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    store_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('store.id'), nullable=False)
    store = relationship('Store')

class Store(Base):
    status = Column(Enum('published', 'verify', 'no_position',
                         name='store_status'),
                    nullable=False, default='verify')
    type = Column(Enum('physical', 'web', name='store_type'),
                  nullable=False, default='physical')
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    street = Column(Text)
    postal_code = Column(Text)
    city = Column(Text)
    country = Column(Text)
    phone_number = Column(Text)
    email = Column(Text)
    website = Column(Text)
    location = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326))
    is_flagship = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    images = relationship(StoreImage)
```

Now what I want to do is query like this:

```
q = Store.query.filter(Store.is_flagship == True).with_entities(
    Store.id,
    Store.status,
    Store.slug,
    Store.type,
    Store.name,
    Store.street,
    Store.postal_code,
    Store.city,
    Store.country,
    Store.phone_number,
    Store.email,
    Store.website,
    func.ST_AsGeoJSON(Store.location).label('location'),
    Store.images,
)
```

The query works, but `Store.images` just returns `True` for every row. How can I make it return a list of `StoreImage` instances/KeyedTuples?

I want to do it this way mainly because I haven't found any other way to make `Store.query` return the location in GeoJSON format.

EDIT: One solution for me would be to just return `Store` instances from the query and somehow add in `location` GeoJSON, either on the declared model or some other way if possible. Don't know how to do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query not only returns *wrong* value, but in fact returns wrong number of rows, because it will perform a cartesian product of both tables.
Also I would not overwrite the column name `location`. So I will use `geo_location` in the code below.

You are right, and in order to pre-load images, you have to query for the whole `Store` instances. For example, like the query below:

```
q = (session.query(Store)
        .outerjoin(Store.images) # load images
        .options(contains_eager(Store.images)) # tell SA that we hav loaded them so that it will not perform another query
        .filter(Store.is_flagship == True)
    ).all()
```

In order to combine the two, you can do the following:

```
q = (session.query(Store, func.ST_AsGeoJSON(Store.location).label('geo_location'))
        .outerjoin(Store.images) # load images
        .options(contains_eager(Store.images)) # tell SA that we hav loaded them so that it will not perform another query
        .filter(Store.is_flagship == True)
    ).all()

# patch values in the instances of Store:
for store, geo_location in q:
    store.geo_location = geo_location
```

**Edit-1:** Alternatively try using [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.column_property)

```
class Store(...):
    # ...
    location_json = column_property(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(location).label('location_json'))

    q = (session.query(Store).label('geo_location'))
            .outerjoin(Store.images) # load images
            .options(contains_eager(Store.images)) # tell SA that we hav loaded them so that it will not perform another query
            .filter(Store.is_flagship == True)
        ).all()
    for store in q:
        print(q.location_json)
        print(len(q.images))
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining @van. Is it possible to not have it returned as a two-tuple with Store at first index and location at second? Perhaps with `Bundle`?

Comment: These are actually instances of [`KeyedTuple`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple), and I think the `Bundle` will give you the same end result. But why don't you try using [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.column_property). I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks @van, `column_property` does exactly what I needed.